# Обработка HTML-тегов на Perl

Tags: html, парсер, perl

Нужно из некоторых тегов вырезать контент, а некоторые просто удалить. Например, вот это:

```
baz<foo>foo</foo><bar>bar</bar>
```

должно превратиться в:

```
baz bar
```

Регекспами не предлагать :) [HTML::TagFilter](http://search.cpan.org/~wross/HTML-TagFilter-1.03/TagFilter.pm) не умеет первое, а больше ничего готового в голову не лезет...

UPD: [Моя поделка на HTTP::Parser](http://klopp.net.ru/Perl/HTML/TagRemover.pm)

Comment: А давайте лучше регекспами?  
Плюсы очевидны:  
простота поддержки  
краткость кода  
и многое другое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=HTML&mode=all)

например

- [HTML::Parser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~rsavage/HTML-Parser-Simple-2.00/lib/HTML/Parser/Simple.pm)
- [HTML::HTML5::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/~tobyink/HTML-HTML5-DOM-0.001/lib/HTML/HTML5/DOM.pm)
- [HTML::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/HTML-DOM-0.053/lib/HTML/DOM.pm)

Comment: Про парсеры были мысли, но это не совсем укладывается в "готовое решение".

Comment: в смысле ? вам пример нужен как использовать один  из пакетов для манипуляций с DOM ? в описании есть примеры.

Comment: Да нет, как написать обработчики событий я знаю :) Просто может что уже совсем готовое есть, куда списки тегов в аргументах передать надо и всё. В общем, сделал на HTML::Parser, а DOM слишком тяжёлый для таких задач.

Comment: См. UPD и коммент ниже :)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [Mojo::DOM](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM)

Comment: И тянуть весь Mojo?

Comment: Тянуть Mojo вас смущает, а тянуть зависимости у HTML::TagFilter вас не смущает?

Comment: Если что, вот список зависимостей HTML::Parser, который использует тэгфильтр: http://perlmonks.org/?node=cpan+module+search&pivot=1&module=HTML%3A%3AParser

Comment: Я знаю, какие зависимости у TagFilter :) Это всё и так есть. К тому же решения на DOM намного тяжелей, проверено. Впрочем, надо погонять бенчмарки, посмотрим.

Comment: До Mojo так не дошёл :) Но:

    #!/usr/bin/perl
    
    use strict;
    use Benchmark qw(:all);
    use HTML::Parser;
    use HTML::DOM;
    
    my $dp = new HTML::DOM; 
    my $hp = new HTML::Parser;     
    my $t = timeit(10000, sub { eval{$hp->parse_file('1.html');} });
    print "Parser",timestr($t),"\n";
    $t = timeit(10000, sub { eval{$dp->parse_file('1.html');} });
    print "DOM",timestr($t),"\n";

И:

    Parser 0 wallclock secs ( 0.12 usr +  0.39 sys =  0.52 CPU) @ 19379.84/s (n=10000)
    DOM 7 wallclock secs ( 3.81 usr +  3.22 sys =  7.03 CPU) @ 1422.27/s (n=10000)

Comment: Вот когда начнете работать с реальными задачами, на регулярно изменяющихся источниках, тогда оцените прелесть DOM.

Comment: Я знаю для каких задач хорош DOM, спасибо, а ваши предположения о моих задачах и иначинаниях мне не интересны.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) - Парсер, строящий дерево HTML